# C# Append Newline To <p> tags in HTML fragment

Tags: c#, html, regex, replace, newline

I've done this but it feels dirty and wrong.  What are some better alternatives?

```
private static string addNewLinesToStoryParagraphs(string story)
{
    string result = story.Replace("</p>", "</p>" + Environment.NewLine);
    result = result.Replace("</p>" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, "</p>" + Environment.NewLine);
    return result;
}
```

The input string is an HTML fragment serialized to a string.  I want to make sure there is a new line for every `<p></p>` pair.  Obviously if the NewLine already exists I don't want to have two lines between each `<p></p>` pair.

I briefly looked at trying something with the HTML Agility Pack, but I didn't see any save overload or options for cleaning up HTML.  I've got very little experience with that library however so if there is a way to do it I'm all ears.

Comment: `Regex.Replace(input,"</p>(?![\n\r]+)","</p>"+Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: @Anirudh That's an acceptable answer.  Can you please make this an answer so it can be voted and accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(input,"</p>(?![\n\r]+)","</p>"+Environment.NewLine);
```